# ULG files are taking 25 GB disk space

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage

I would like to know what ULG files are on Ubuntu. After trying to find what was using the disk space, I found a directory using 25 GB of 28 GB total, and this directory had 785 ULG files.

Note that I'm working on an Intel Aero RTF, using Ubuntu 16.04, and it can store 28 GB.

Output of `du` command (the essential part):

```
root@intel-aero:/var/lib/mavlink-router# du -h /var/lib/mavlink-router/
25G /var/lib/mavlink-router/
```

Number of files:

```
root@intel-aero:/var/lib/mavlink-router# find /var/lib/mavlink-router/ -type f | wc -l
785
```

Partial results of `ls`:

```
root@intel-aero:/var/lib/mavlink-router# ls -lh
total 25G
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   73M May 22 05:45 00000-2018-05-22_05-14-52.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   36M May 22 06:00 00001-2018-05-22_05-45-23.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9.0M May 22 05:00 00002-2018-05-22_04-57-05.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11M May 22 05:01 00003-2018-05-22_04-57-05.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  117M May 22 05:46 00004-2018-05-22_04-57-05.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  220M May 22  2018 00005-2018-05-22_04-57-05.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 May 22  2018 00006-2018-05-22_06-31-13.ulg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 May 22  2018 00007-2018-05-22_06-31-14.ulg
```

`df` result:

```
root@intel-aero:/var/lib/mavlink-router# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        28G   28G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   76M  1.8G   4% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G   48K  1.9G   1% /var/volatile
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p1   28M  7.7M   21M  28% /boot
tmpfs           382M     0  382M   0% /run/user/0
```

So questions are:

- What type of file is a ULG file? Is it a save, config, ... ?
- Can I remove some of them (or all of them) without any issue later?

Comment: so can i remove them? I can't even transfer a 400 kB file because of that overused space

Comment: [mavlink-router](https://github.com/intel/mavlink-router) - Route mavlink packets between endpoints. ULog is the file format used for logging system data. The format is self-describing, i.e. it contains the format and message types that are logged. If the .ulg files are log files maybe you can read part of one of them to check if it is a log file and therefore it can be deleted except for the most recent log files. According to [ULog File Format](https://dev.px4.io/en/log/ulog_file_format.html) mavlink-router: C++, ULog streaming via MAVLink.

Comment: @PerlDuck Please post it as an answer.

Comment: I'll let you do it. It's fairer that way because I got the smaller half.

Comment: @damadam I have no idea what an _Intel Aero RTF_ is, but doesn't it have `logrotate` installed? That might be a third … workaround.

Comment: `logrotate` is available, it is installed on Ubuntu16.04 by default, see this drone like a computer (it has got an Atom x7, just a little slower than a computer :D)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to a similar question in an Intel forum, [*Disk fills up, large ULG files in /var/lib/mavlink-router*](https://communities.intel.com/thread/124446), these ULG files are logfiles of the [mavlink-router](https://github.com/intel/mavlink-router).

There are only two workarounds:

- Either disable logging:

  > Modify `/etc/mavlink-router/main.conf` and comment out the line below:
  >
  > ```
  > [General]
  > #Log=/var/log/mavlink-router
  > ```
- Or setup a cronjob to delete them regularly once a day:

  > ```
  > 0 2 * * * rm /var/lib/mavlink-router/*.ulg && systemctl restart mavlink-router.service
  > ```

---

At first, I thought `logrotate` with the following snippet could be of help:

```
/var/lib/mavlink-router/*.ulg {
    rotate 2
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        systemctl restart mavlink-router.service
    endscript
}
```

**But this won't work as intended** because the filenames already have a timestamp and number in them, so each file has a different name and `logrotate` would simply compress them but never delete them. E.g. `00000-2018-05-22_05-14-52.ulg` would become `00000-2018-05-22_05-14-52.ulg.1.gz` but never get deleted because there won't be another file with that name that claims its place.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23108631/5830574) for a possible solution with `logrotate` for files with timestamps in their name.

Comment: Instead of just removing all logfiles daily, you could use `find` to delete files older that some days or weeks, should you ever need to investigate some old incident.