# Disabling "iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707" from flooding the logs

Tags: 18.04, log, iwlwifi

I have a certain problem with my wifi card, which makes the following message :

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

be outputted a dozen of times per second to the `syslog` and `kern.log` files in `/var/logs` whenever connected.

The problem with the wifi card itself is a long-running one that I tried and failed many times to solve, but weirdly enough the wifi still works correctly, so I'm not asking specifically to tackle it down.

The problem is said log files grow of around 4 MB per minutes for a hefty 5 GB per day.
The `/var` directory is its own partition, so that limits problems, but I still need to force a `logrotate` and delete archived files any time I want to run an `apt upgrade`, for example, reading the log files for any reason is impossible, as well as using the ttys because that message is also outputted on them.

Would there be a way to disable the outputting of that message to the logs?

Config :

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Kernel 5.0.0-36-generic
- Wifi card : Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560

Edit :

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 
[sudo] password for penwywern: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (5.0.0.36.94). 
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

Comment: the best would be to solve this spamming print error would be to solve what is this little issue of the wifi card :D

Comment: @damadam well, rather obviously, but as I said, I've already tried to for a long time, with no result at all, and seeing how the impact on the functionality of the card is (arguably very weirdly) minimal, I'm ok with it staying that way, if it could just shut the goddam hell up about it.

I'll obviously keep trying to solve it, but if in the meantime I could access my `var/logs`, not need to manually remove the logs whenever I want to do anything in /var, and actually use the ttys (because it also floods the ttys) that'd be nice

Comment: you could try to set a cronjob (modifying timestamp value has you want to clear your log file) like said in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064089/829702) : so it could be something like `0 2 * * * rm /var/log/kern.log | touch /var/log/kern.log` (this one clear once a day)

Comment: That would work, but I'd prefer not removing the logs, as they can be rather useful, especially for debugging, and it wouldn't solve the problem of the ttys being also flooded by that message.
Is there really no way to control what's outputted to the logs?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/973632/ubuntu-18-04-lts-crashes-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t590  : enable HWE and you will pull in the fix for this. Seems solvable to me ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I already tried that and it did nothing to change the problem.

Once again, it is a problem I have already dredged the internet far and wide to try and solve, so I think I already tried most of the proposed solutions to it.

My question here is really about trying to control the output to the logs and the ttys

Comment: if that was true you'd be on kernel 5.2 or 5.3 and not 5.0.

Comment: ~~~sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 
[sudo] password for penwywern: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (5.0.0.36.94).
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.~~~
don't know how to put screenshots in comments but here you go.
Why on all earths would I lie about this?

Comment: sorry, apparently don't know how to put code blocks in comments either

Comment: @Rinzwind The current hwe kernel for 18.04 is 5.0.0-36. The OP has the correct one installed.

Comment: @Penwywern instead of adding code result / screenshot in comment, just edit the question, so you can ping to answer that you had added a result in edit (I had done it for you)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to solve this problem too and I think I did it.
I turned off some encryption option in iwlwifi and I'm not seeing the constant stream of "Unhandled alg" errors in my log files anymore.

I added this line:

```
options iwlwifi swcrypto=0
```

To this file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and rebooted.

If you need whatever "swcrypto" does, I guess this isn't the best option. But maybe this helps others figure out the problem?

Comment: `swcrypto=0` switches from software encryption to hardware encryption. Thanks, but, tried it already, doesn't work for me. And really, you shouldn't changes things when you don't at least know roughly what they are. Even when it's minor and reversible like here.